# vector iterating over itself

Tags: c++, c

In my project I have a vector wit some relational data (a struct that holds two similar objects which represent a relationship between them) and I need to check for relationships combinations between all data in the vector.

What I am doing is iterating over the vector and inside the first for loop I am iterating again to look for relationships between data.

This is a simplified model of what I am doing

```
for(a=0; a<vec.size(); a++)
{
    for(b=0; b<vec.size(); b++)
    {
        if(vec[a].something==vec[b].something) {...}
    }
}
```

My collection has 2800 elements which means that I will be iterating 2800*2800 times...

What kind of data structure is more suitable for this kind of operation? 
Would using for_each be any faster then traversing the vector like this?

Thanks in advance!

---

vec has two structs which are made up of two integers and nothing is ordered.

Comment: Perhaps use a multimap that maps values to indexes or iterators.

Comment: Vector is pretty much the best for this, what you need is an algo that isn't n^2

Comment: sorted vector then use 1st `b = a + 1` in inner loop

Comment: What kind of elements? Numbers? Strings? Or something more complex? If the items are somehow sortable, check out the quick select algorithm.

Comment: Do you have any kind of order for your elements?

Comment: What is `something`?  You might not consider it important, but the solution to your problem lies in the structure of `something`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, for_each still does the same thing.

Using a hash map could make your problem better.  Start with an empty hash and iterate through the list.  For each element, see if it's in the hash.  If it's not, add it.  If it is, then you have a duplicate and you run your code.

In C++, you can use std::map.  In C, there is no built in map datastructure, so you'd have to make your own.

The high-level pseudo code would look something like this

```
foreach (element in array)
  if map.has_key(element)
    do_stuff(element)
  else
    map.add_key(element)
```

Comment: I don't think we can consider this a useful answer because we can't give one without knowing more about his problem

Comment: As long as they key is the "relationship", I think it can work.  Perhaps not quite as simply, but pretty sure it's still a valid approach

Comment: it's definitely possible that a map or `unordered_map` is a good solution but we know nothing about the problem, we don't even know what data type is in the vector for godsakes

Comment: +1 now your answer makes sense since he actually has some real info on his problem

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to improve the efficiency of this operation would be to sort the vector and then look for duplicates.  If sorting the vector isn't an option, you could create another vector of pointers to the elements of this vector and sort that.  Both of those will take you from an N**2 complexity to an N*log(N) complexity (assuming, of course, that you use an N*log(N) sort).  This does mean using more space, but often using a bit of space for significant time improvements is very reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your vector contains a "relation" structure like:

```
class Entity;

struct Relation {
  Entity* something;
  Entity* relative;
};
```

and you have a vector of "relations":

```
std::vector<Relation> ties;
```

So if I understood it correctly, you want to segment ties and have a list of Relations for each Entity. This may be represented by a map:

```
std::map<Entity*,std::vector<Relation*>> entityTiesIndex;
```

Then you could just scan **once** through all ties and collect the relations for each entity:

```
for (int i=0; i < ties.size(); ++i ) {
  Relation* relation = &ties[i];
  entityTiesIndex[relation->something].push_back(relation);
}
```

Mind here the usual disclaimer about *references to container elements*, as these may change when container is altered.

Hope this makes sense.